# laravel 5.4 LengthAwarePaginator lose pages results

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm using the LengthAwarePaginator to paginate the results of my collection,

```
$all_products = $all_products->where('scat_id', $sub_category);
$products = $this->manuallyPaginate($all_products);
```

all_products its the collection of my products, then I used the laravel where method to filtrate, after that manuallyPaginate its executed

```
private function manuallyPaginate($array){

    $total = count($array);
    $perPage = 15;
    $currentPage = Input::get('page', 1);
    $paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator($array, 
        $total, 
        $perPage, 
        $currentPage,
        ['path'  => url()->current()]
    );

    return $paginator;
}
```

This works, but all products are shown in every page instead of 15 per page.
am I missing a parameter to LengthAwarePaginator method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the current page. For each page you set the currentPage variable to 1.

Try use something like `$_GET['page']` or `Input::get('page', 1)` to set the current page value from the url to `$currentPage`.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `manuallyPaginate()`, you never change `$currentPage`. 
You should set it to the GET `page` parameter using the [Input facade](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.html):

```
$currentPage = Input::get('page', 1);
```

The [`Input::get()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.html#method_get) method accepts a second parameter which will be the default value if the attribute is not set.

Comment: This worked! Its solved the links issue but all results are rendering at the first page, Instead of showing 15 per page, every page shows all results

Comment: Here is a solution I came up with : https://pastebin.com/jfayFCs1
The idea is to only give the desired items to the paginator via `array_splice` and manually calculating the offset.
I'm not sure if it's the cleanest way to do but it works.

Comment: I can't acces this site  pastebin.com/jfayFCs1

Comment: I tried your solution but this error was given  array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given <- its because its a collection, not an array

Comment: You can use the [Collection::slice()](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_slice) method then.